# How to list the number of automobile crashes associated with each weather type in the descending order?

Tags: sql

I have a database with 12,000 records with various attributes. One of them is weather_condition (Integer).

This query will return every single car accident with weather type in descending order.

```
SELECT weather_condition FROM nyccrash ORDER BY weather_condition DESC;
```

What I want specifically is to display the count of how many accidents associated with each weather_condition. There are 7 conditions: 0 through 7.

For example:

```
Condition | Count
0         | 452
1         | 558
2         | 1242
3         | 92
...       | ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT weather_condition, COUNT(weather_condition) AS Count 
FROM nyccrash
GROUP BY weather_condition
ORDER BY weather_condition DESC ;
```

Comment: Your Order By needs to be after your Group By.  Other than that, this one should work fine.

Comment: @MichaelRice Yah, I noticed that little faux pas and fixed it already. Thanks!